# Determining the number of decimal digits in a floating number

Tags: c, for-loop, floating-point

I am trying to write a program that outputs the number of the digits in the decimal portion of a given number (`0.128`).

I made the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main(){

    float result = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int exp = 0;
    
    for(exp = 0; int(1+result) % 10 != 0; exp++)
    {
        result = 0.128 * pow(10, exp);
        count++;
    }
    printf("%d \n", count);
    printf("%f \n", result);

    return 0;
}
```

What I had in mind was that `exp` keeps being incremented until `int(1+result) % 10` outputs `0`. So for example when `result = 0.128 * pow(10,4) = 1280`, result mod 10 (`int(1+result) % 10`) will output `0` and the loop will stop.

I know that on a bigger scale this method is still inefficient since if `result` was a given input like `1.1208` the program would basically stop at one digit short of the desired value; however, I am trying to first find out the reason why I'm facing the current issue.

**My Issue**: The loop won't just stop at `1280`; it keeps looping until its value reaches `128000000.000000`.

Here is the output when I run the program:

```
10 
128000000.000000
```

Apologies if my description is vague, any given help is very much appreciated.

Comment: *I am trying to write a program that outputs the number of the digits in the decimal portion of a given number* -- Good luck with this, because you're going to need it.  This task is not trivial, and maybe impossible to get correct.  Who gave you this assignment, given the complexities and possible "no way this can be done" scenario?

Comment: but (1280+1)%10 is 1, not 0...?

Comment: anyway, floating point numbers **don't have** decimal digits in them, only binary digits. The number of binary digits in a float is 24.

Comment: Unless the number is inputted as a string and then check for the `'.'`, I don't see any way to correctly do this that will work for all cases.  Even in your code, you've messed things up by using `pow`, compounding the issue of floating point numbers being approximations.

Comment: btw your current approach is not ineffcient, but wrong. You already know why, but "inefficient" is the wrong term

Comment: OK, so is this an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/)?

Comment: @roobigol Is converting the number to a `char` array using `snprintf` and then evaluating that array an option?

Comment: @Yun -- Assuming `snprintf` doesn't mess the number up due to approximations...

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie there is no way to answer the question without "messing the number up due to approximations"

Comment: Hardware implementations aside, you could argue that any floating point number has an infinite number of decimal digits, some of which may be zero.

Comment: @user253751 Not impossible.  I'd expect a good `*printf()` to well handle `LDBL_DECIMAL_DIGS + 3` significant digts.  Past that, yes, it it is [work](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/212490/29485).

Comment: Roughly speaking, the number of digits in a `float` number is `FLT_DIG`.  You don't even need to do any math to compute it!

Comment: `int(1+result)` looks like C++, not C.  I think you meant `(int)(1+result)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am trying to write a program that outputs the number of the digits in the decimal portion of a given number (`0.128`).

This task is basically impossible, because on a conventional (binary) machine the goal is not meaningful.

If I write

```
float f = 0.128;
printf("%f\n", f);
```

I see

```
0.128000
```

and I might conclude that 0.128 has three digits.  (Never mind about the three `0`'s.)

But if I then write

```
printf("%.15f\n", f);
```

I see

```
0.128000006079674
```

Wait a minute!  What's going on?  Now how many digits does it have?

It's customary to say that floating-point numbers are "not accurate" or that they suffer from "roundoff error".  But in fact, floating-point numbers are, in their own way, perfectly accurate — it's just that they're accurate *in base two*, not the base 10 we're used to thinking about.

The surprising fact is that most decimal (base 10) fractions *do not exist* as finite binary fractions.  This is similar to the way that the number 1/3 does not even exist as a finite decimal fraction.  You can approximate 1/3 as 0.333 or 0.3333333333 or 0.33333333333333333333, but without an infinite number of 3's it's only an approximation.  Similarly, you can approximate 1/10 in base 2 as `0b0.00011` or `0b0.000110011` or `0b0.000110011001100110011001100110011`, but without an infinite number of `0011`'s it, too, is only an approximation.  (That last rendition, with 33 bits past the binary point, works out to about 0.0999999999767.)

And it's the same with most decimal fractions you can think of, including 0.128.  So when I wrote

```
float f = 0.128;
```

what I actually got in `f` was the binary number `0b0.00100000110001001001101111`, which in decimal is exactly 0.12800000607967376708984375.

Once a number has been stored as a `float` (or a `double`, for that matter) it is what it is: there is no way to rediscover that it was initially initialized from a "nice, round" decimal fraction like 0.128.  And if you try to "count the number of decimal digits", and if your code does a really precise job, you're liable to get an answer of 26 (that is, corresponding to the digits "12800000607967376708984375"), not 3.

---

P.S. ***If*** you were working with computer hardware that implemented decimal floating point, this problem's goal would be meaningful, possible, and tractable.  And implementations of decimal floating point do exist.  But the ordinary `float` and `double` values any of is likely to use on any of today's common, mass-market computers are invariably going to be binary (specifically, conforming to [IEEE-754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754)).

---

P.P.S. Above I wrote, "what I actually got in `f` was the binary number `0b0.00100000110001001001101111`".  And if you count the number of significant bits there — `100000110001001001101111` — you get 24, which is no coincidence at all.  You can read at [single precision floating-point format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) that the significand portion of a `float` has 24 bits (with 23 explicitly stored), and here, you're seeing that in action.

Answer (score 2):

**`float` vs. code**

A binary `float` cannot encode 0.128 exactly as it is not a [dyadic rational](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadic_rational).
Instead, it takes on a nearby value: 0.12800000607967376708984375. 26 digits.

**Rounding errors**

OP's approach incurs rounding errors in `result = 0.128 * pow(10, exp);`.

**Extended math needed**

The goal is difficult. Example: `FLT_TRUE_MIN` takes about [149](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/212490/29485) digits.

We could use `double` or `long double` to get us somewhat there.
Simply multiply the fraction by 10.0 in each step.
`d *= 10.0;` still incurs rounding errors, but less so than OP's approach.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h> int main(){
    int count = 0;

    float f =  0.128f;
    double d =  f - trunc(f);
    printf("%.30f\n", d);
    while (d) {
      d *= 10.0;
      double ipart = trunc(d);
      printf("%.0f", ipart);
      d -= ipart;
      count++;
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("%d \n", count);
    return 0;
 }
```

Output

```
0.128000006079673767089843750000
12800000607967376708984375
26
```

**Usefulness**

Typically, past `FLT_DECMAL_DIG` (9) or so significant decimal places, OP’s goal is usually not that useful.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, the number of *decimal* digits is meaningless when using *binary* floating-point.

But you also have a flawed termination condition.  The loop test is `(int)(1+result) % 10 != 0` meaning that it will stop whenever we reach an integer whose last digit is 9.

That means that `0.9`, `0.99` and `0.9999` all give a result of `2`.

We also lose precision by truncating the `double` value we start with by storing into a `float`.

The most useful thing we could do is terminate when the remaining fractional part is less than the precision of the type used.

---

Suggested working code:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <float.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    double val = 0.128;
    double prec = DBL_EPSILON;
    double result;
    int count = 0;

    while (fabs(modf(val, &result)) > prec) {
        ++count;
        val *= 10;
        prec *= 10;
    }
    printf("%d digit(s): %0*.0f\n", count, count, result);
}
```

Results:

```
3 digit(s): 128
```